# How do I get posts by multiple post ID's?

Tags: get-posts

I've got a string with post ID's: `43,23,65`.
I was hoping I could use `get_posts()` and use the string with ID's as an argument.

But I can't find any functions for retrieving multiple posts by ID.

Do I really have to do a `WP_query`?

I've also seen someone mention using `tag_in` - but I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: have you tried to use the 'include' argument of `get_posts()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) as it takes the same arguments as `WP_Query`.

To pass it the IDs, use `'post__in' => array(43,23,65)` (only takes arrays).

Something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array(43,23,65)
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $p) :
    //post!
endforeach;
```

I'd also set the `post_type` and `posts_per_page` just for good measure.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: No? Are you passing it as an array? Using two underscores (post__in vs post_in)? Passing a post_type?

Comment: If you're getting a custom post type, use the `post_type` argument, and if you want more than 5 results, add the `'nopaging' => true` option.

If you have a comma seperated string instead of an array, use `explode(',',$input);` to convert to array.

Comment: If you wanted to keep the order of the posts the way they're passed by the `array`, make sure to add `'order_by' => 'post__in'` to your `$args`.

Comment: beware using `post_type` parameter. In case of `post`, function will return *ALL* content types, including your custom ones, not just `post`.

Comment: Just make sure to check the status of the post ids. Should be 'publish'

Answer (score 6):

If you can't get the above to work, make sure you add `post_type`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pt_case_study',
    'post__in' => array(2417, 2112, 784)
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the posts by their IDs (regardless of post type) use this:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => get_post_types(),
    'post__in' => [ 43, 23, 65 ]
];

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Or even shorter:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post__in' => [ 43, 23, 65 ]
];

$posts = get_posts($args);
```